# How to handle localized numeric values in Xpage?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a Xpage with three fields, all Number declared; Nominal, Price and PaymentAmount.
I want to calculate the PaymentAmount using Nominal * Price.

In SSJS onChange I use the following code:

```
var price = getComponent("Price").getValue();
```

to get the value from the field "Price".

In Sweden we enter our numeric values as this #.###,## 1.234,56

If I enter the values Nominal=10 and Price=2,5 in my Xpage and try to calculate using the above mentioned formula the value stored in var "price" is converted to 25 and of type long.

Please advice

/M

Comment: If the Editbox is set to any type of "number" (Number, Currency…) getValue() will return a long if the value if the field is 2,5. It will convert it and remove the fraction as 2,5 -> 25

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot, unfortunatly.

Did this:

```
<inputText value="#{document1.Price}" id="Price" required="true" size="10">
    <this.validators>
        <validateRequired message="Price is required">
        </validateRequired>
    </this.validators>
    <this.converter>
        <convertNumber type="number" locale="sv">
        </convertNumber>**
    </this.converter>
</inputText>
```

and it works!

Thanks you ALL for input

Comment: OK good. I did not notice this before I updated my answer but there is some more info too now.

Answer (score 0):

I take it "Price" is an edit box? If so you can set it to Number field, then Display format to currency. The currency code will define how that number is displayed.

[image]

When you get the components value it should come back as a normal number you can work with.

Comment: Price is a Number field and the getValue() will return a String but if the "type" property is set to "number" the getValue() is returning a long, hence removing all fractions… 2,5 became 25

Comment: When set to Currency the result is double although fraction still removed and the result is 25 (2,5)…

Answer (score 0):

`getComponent` gets the UI component value and that's why it does not necessarily reflect the data type that will be saved (in UI everything is string). It's also a slow way to get the value.

Try `datasourcename.getItemValueDouble("itemname")` instead. Note that you need to use the field name on Form, not the component name.

Regarding number format make sure your djConfig locale is Sweden, probably `se-se`. For me in Finland it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="locale: 'fi-fi', parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

It should use the browser locale. To force this in SSJS you can do:

```
context.setLocaleString("se-SE");
```

in *beforePageLoad* event.

Comment: Updated the answer with some info.

Comment: I tested that now and with no effect, I'm afraid. I'm stuck…

Comment: @MikaelGrevsten by "no effect" do you meand the locale did not change in the HTML source or still troubles with the currency field? This changes the locale in HTML for me in 8.5.3FP3.

Comment: OK, I have set the locale string as you suggested. The EditBox is defined as Number with type Currency. getComponent("Price").getValue() is returning a long value of 25 instead of a value of 2,5 (string or double). The only way to get a value from the field I can work with is to declare it as a string but then it will be stored as such and it will be wrong.