# dojo errors in Xpages

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

Using Notes 8.5.3, UP1, I have a long XPage which uses a lot of ExtLib functions.  I'm also using TinyMCE and a jQuery table of contents, described here: http://xomino.com/2012/08/26/jquery-in-xpages-14-toc-create-a-menu-to-scroll-to-a-form-section/.  When I create a new document it works fine and saves properly.  However, once it's opened in edit mode again, I get the following errors in Firebug:

```
TypeError: node is null
    dojo.js, line 14.
Error parsing in _ContentSetter#Setter_view:id1:id9:callback:tabName_pane_6
    file "xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.en-us/@Fv&@EOb&@EOd&@EOf&@Ek&@Es&@Ie&@Ig.js", line 82
Error undefined running custom onLoad code:  This deferred has already been resolved.
    file "xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.en-us/@Fv&@EOb&@EOd&@EOf&@Ek&@Es&@Ie&@Ig.js", line 82
```

Basically, these errors are preventing any SSJS from being triggered at all.  Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: First you should disable the resource aggregation of your XPage app. This gives you a better information which JavaScript library contains the error. Then check the onLoad events (CSJS) of pane6.

Comment: Thanks!  It's a long form, so I just removed the panel that had a lot of stuff in it, and no more errors.  I'll see what's wrong in there and should be good from here.  Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a field with a date picker?

Comment: Several... this is the problem.  I still want to show the date pickers, however, they are still causing the problems.

Tried Sven's theme trick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715649/set-locale-on-view-columns-date-fields-in-theme-xpages), but doesn't seem to work for editable date pickers.